# error A2094: operand must be relocatable MASM32

Tags: assembly, masm32

What the code does is calling the MessageBox, then depends on what I click YES/NO/CANCEL I get 6/7/2 in eax register. If I click CANCEL it jumps to the end of program, if I click YES or NO it goes to the "cond" macros where IF ELSE statement is located.
Main code:

```
TITLE <Зовнішні процедури>
.686
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none
include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc
include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include lab51.inc
include lab52.inc
include ifelse.inc

.data
MsgBoxText db "Yes-lab1 No-lab2 Cancel-Exit", 0
MsgBoxCaption db "Вибір", 0

MsgBoxTextLab1 db "Data transfer and modification", 0
MsgBoxCaptionLab1 db "Lab1", 0

MsgBoxTextLab2 db "y=a^4-3b/2d", 0
MsgBoxCaptionLab2 db "Lab2", 0

X dd 32127212h, 43121153h, 21344214h, 0064216340h, 23243245h, 51542145h
Y1 db 12 DUP(0FFh)
Y2 db 12 DUP(0FFh)
Y3 db 12 DUP(0FFh)
Y4 db 12 DUP(0FFh)
sumres dd 0


a SDWORD 3,-2,-4,5,10
b DWORD 5,7,10,15,25
d SDWORD -7,-2,-4,-12,-34
y SWORD 5 DUP (7777h)
td dd 0
res dw 0

cvar db 0


.code

start:
xor eax, eax
INVOKE MessageBox, NULL, addr MsgBoxText, addr MsgBoxCaption,\ 
                    MB_YESNOCANCEL+MB_SYSTEMMODAL+MB_ICONQUESTION

cmp eax, 2
je exitp    
sub eax, 6
mov cvar, al
cond cvar    
exitp:
INVOKE ExitProcess, 0 
end start
```

ifelse.inc:

```
cond MACRO bo
IF bo eq 0
    labOne offset X, offset Y1, offset Y2, offset Y3, offset Y4, offset sumres
    EXITM
ELSE
    labTwo offset a, offset b, offset d, offset y, offset td, offset res
    EXITM
ENDIF
ENDM
```

The problem is that I get 'error A2094: operand must be relocatable' in line where I call macros. How can I fix this? There were no problems with other variables in other macroses.

Mistake that I get [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwXkF.png)

Comment: For starters you are using a compile-time construct when you want a runtime condition so that won't work. Also you are trying to put data in the middle of code.

Comment: `.if` is the runtime thing that emits cmp/jcc instructions for you, `if` is the assemble-time directive like CPP `#if` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-if?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your replies. It was task for my lab to use IFELSE statement in a macros and I decided to give up the idea of MessageBox with a choice and just compiled two programs using constants as an argument for this macros.